# how to check if on slave jenkins via shell script

Tags: jenkins

I am running a build using jenkins. I need to send a file to master if the build is running on a slave node. How do I write a bash script (and get jenkins to execute the script) that checks to see if the node is master? If the node is master, jenkins should do X, if its a slave, jenkins should do Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather not use a shell script for this, since it'd make your builds non-portable.

I'd use the [Copy To Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) which supports also the other way round:

> #### Copy files back to master node
>
> To activate this plugin for a given job, simply check the **Copy files back to the job's workspace on the master node** checkbox in the **Post-build Actions** section of the job. You then get the same two fields as for the **Copy files to slave node before building** section.

From the inline help:

> When a build taking place on a slave node completes, copies a set of files from this slave node back to the master one.
> Of course, no copy will take place if the build was run on the master node.

---

For the node a build is running on see [Jenkins Set Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables):

> NODE_NAME   The name of the node the current build is running on. Equals 'master' for master node.